# Can't get AVFoundation Pause () working in CollectionView

Tags: swift, avfoundation

In my app I have a collectionViewCell that plays music, In the collectionViewCell class I made the player variable

```
 var player: AVAudioPlayer?
```

I also tried:

```
var player = AVAudioplayer()
```

I made a method pauseMusic ()

```
func pauseMusic (){

    if player != nil {
    if player!.playing == true{

    player!.pause()
       }
    }
}
```

When I call this pauseMusic() method from my FirstViewController in the UIBarButtonItem action, my app crashes

```
 @IBAction func pauseButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var colVW = CollectionViewCell()
    colVW.pauseMusic()
}
```

I also uploaded this screenshot that shows the error when it crashes

http://nl.tinypic.com/r/t66zir/8

Is anybody familiar with this crash?
I would really appreciate if you could give me some advice!

**Additional code:**

This func checks which song has to be played, this func lives in the CollectionView. Because of the link between this func and the CollectionViewCell class, I can't move the AVPlayer somewhere else..

```
func prepareAudios() {

   var songIndexString = (imageOutlet.titleLabel?.text)!
    //println(songIndexString)

    var songIndex = (songIndexString.toInt())!

    println("songIndex: \(songIndex)")

    if musicStopped == true {

        rateButton()
        println("empty")

    } else if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioArray[songIndex], ofType: "mp3"){

        var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
        player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
        player!.play()

    } else {
        println("Path for audio file not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to have AVPlayer instance inside UICollectionView cell. You could have it inside controller or some other object which would be used when there is some interaction inside the cell. But having a player sounds somewhat strange. The problem might be due to your player going nil. When do you create the AVPlayer and how do you use it. It would be helpful if you could provide some code.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne  
I create the AVPlayer in the CollectionViewCell because each cell has a different song that it plays. The first en secondViewController both have a pause button in the navigationBar, in the pause button action I call the pause function that lives in the CollectionView. I really have no idea how I can fix this.. I added some additional codes in the question